# Сложности с использованием third-party class в проекте (без использования IDE)

Tags: java

Хочу сразу сказать, что в принципе понимаю что просто наживаю себе лишних проблем, но все же. Я пока только на базовом уровне в владею Java, до этого работал в основном в Eclipse, но в учебнике начитался, что в учебных целях лучше работать через коммандную строку, чтобы потеть больше:). Вот разбираюсь с подключением БД к приложению и стал вопрос подключения библиотеки с драйвером для MySQL - который *com.mysql.jdbc.Driver*. 
Все отлично компилируется с указанием -classpath в комманде, а вот при запуске возникает *ClassNotFoundException - com.mysql.jdbc.Driver*, что как я понимаю оно себе не может найти эту библиотеку.

Значит библиотека которую загрузить нужно, если я правильно понял, в файлике *mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar*, который был в комплекте *MySQL Connector/J*. Файл переместил в свой проект, откуда его и использовал для компиляции.
Кстати, тестер класс называется SqlTester, ничего оригинального :)

Использую ОС Win8.1. Что пробовал:

1. Добавлять переменную среды CLASSPATH в систему, как значение переменной писал как просто путь к расположению файла, так и полный адрес с именем файла и расширением. В моем случае это: C:\jsp\omega\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar.
   Это правильно?
2. Пробовал комманду

> java -classpath mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar SqlTester

(файл класса и jar-файл в одной директории были, где я собственно и находился в коммандной строке, для простоты). При этом возникает ошибка, что не может найти главный класс. Кстати, просто сам класс у меня запускается только через ***java -classpath . SqlTester***, хотя и находится в той же директории, но через простую ***java SqlTester*** выдает выше указанную ошибку.
На ХабраХабре нашел отличню статью о использовании коммандной строки, там как пример использования внешней библиотеки была такая комманда

> java -classpath bin:path/to/calculator.jar
>   com.qwertovsky.helloworld.HelloWorld

. Как я ее вижу : java -classpath <внешняя библиотека> <класс>.

Я точно делаю что-то не так, но вот не могу понять что именно.

Comment: ИМХО, лучше не потеть, а сразу пользоваться нормальными инструментами, такими как IDE: IDEA, Eclipse, Netbeans.
Согласен, что понимать, как это все происходит во внутренностях, желательно. Но всю жизнь компилять проекты через командную строку - я врагу такого не пожелаю.

Comment: Но если все же хотите разобраться - выложите код, посмотрим, как можно вам помочь.

Comment: Да, идея именно в том, чтобы разобраться в данном вопросе, побольше граблей по пути собрать:). После работы выложу код и доп инфу. Как это сделать через Eclipse я знаю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
java -classpath .;mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar SqlTester
```

В этом случае подгрузятся классы из текущей директории (обозначено точной в classpath) **и** из архива mysql-connector-java-5.1.35-bin.jar.

Comment: Сработало)) Я не подумал, что это нужно еще чтобы подтягивался класс, который собственно и соединяется с БД. Ответ принят.

Answer (score 1):

Хочу предложить Вам ещё один IDE-less способ попотеть, притом с гораздо большей пользой: воспользуйтесь инструментом для сборки. [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) или [Gradle](http://gradle.org/), например. Вот в этом случае работа с командной строкой исключительно оправдана и по делу. Этот опыт очень пригодится в будущем при освоении автоматизации тестирования, непрерывной интеграции и непрерывного разворачивания.

Несмотря на то, что IDE вроде IntelliJ IDEA принимают во внимание сборочные скрипты Мэйвена и Грэдла, всё равно многое при сборке берёт на себя сама IDE, что в результате может привести к непереносимости сборки на другой компьютер и сильном осложнении совместной разработки. Поэтому привычка к автоматизации сборки с самого начала - крайне полезный навык.

Comment: Обязательно попробую, спасибо за совет :)